# C++/boost::thread program hangs after join_all and return from Main

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

First time posting here, but I've thoroughly search for a solution to this problem and have no solution.  I have a class that calculates the entries for a matrix using basically a statically-scoped thread pool.  When a new calculation needs to be done, a static condition variable signals this.  And when the program ends, a static boolean flag is changed and the main thread calls join_all before exiting.  The problem is that when I return from int main(), the program hangs seemingly during the destruction of the static variables.

Here is the rough source code for the class that performs the calculation:

```
class FunctionCalculator
{
    public:
        static void createWorkers();
        static void destroyWorkers();
        static void calcFunction();

    private:
        static void run();

        static boost::thread_group workers_;
        static boost::mutex theLock_;

        static int curIndex_;
        static unsigned int numCalcsComplete_;

        static boost::condition_variable stateChange_;
        static boost::condition_variable calculationFinished_;

        static bool finished_;

        static struct SharedCalcData { // some vars } calcData_;
};

// static member definitions
int FunctionCalculator::curIndex_;
unsigned int FunctionCalculator::numCalcsComplete_;
boost::mutex FunctionCalculator::theLock_;
boost::condition_variable FunctionCalculator::stateChange_;
boost::condition_variable FunctionCalculator::calculationFinished_;
boost::thread_group FunctionCalculator::workers_;
bool FunctionCalculator::finished_;
FunctionCalculator::SharedCalcData FunctionCalculator::calcData_;

void FunctionCalculator::createWorkers()
{
    finished_ = false;
    curIndex_ = -1;

    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        workers_.create_thread( boost::bind( &FunctionCalculator::run ) );
}

void FunctionCalculator::destroyWorkers()
{
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( theLock_ );

        finished_ = true;
        curIndex_ = 0;

        stateChange_.notify_all();
    }

    workers_.join_all();
}

void FunctionCalculator::run()
{
    unsigned int i = 0; // the column of the matrix to fill in
    while ( true )
    {
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( theLock_ );

            // block if the calculation is finished until there's a new calculation
            while ( curIndex_ < 0 )
                stateChange_.wait( lock );

            // check if it's time for threads to die
            if ( finished_ )
                break;

            // get the next index to process
            i = (unsigned int)curIndex_++;

            // signal all threads to block if this is the last thread in the calculation
            if ( i == 49 )
                curIndex_ = -1;
        }

        // perform calculation/fill in matrix

        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( theLock_ );

            ++numCalcsComplete_;

            // wake up the main thread if this was the last thread in the calculation
            if ( numCalcsComplete_ == 50 )
               calculationFinished_.notify_one();
        }
    }
}

void FunctionCalculator::calcFunction()
{
    // assign calcData_

    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( theLock_ );

        curIndex_         = 0;
        numCalcsComplete_ = 0;

        stateChange_.notify_all();

        while ( curIndex_ >= 0 )
            calculationFinished_.wait( lock );
    }
}
```

Here is some rough code of the main method.  It's actually an object created by main that calls createWorkers() and calcFunction() is actually called by the Gnu Scientific Library (I use static members for this reason), but the idea is this:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    FunctionCalculator fc;

    FunctionCalculator::createWorkers();

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        fc.calcFunction();

    FunctionCalculator::destroyWorkers();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After the call to EXIT_SUCCESS, the program hangs but I have verified that the four threads in FunctionCalculator have finished the run() method after destroyWorkers() is called.  Since the program reaches as far as the return from main, my theory is that the problem happens when the static boost library variables are destroyed at the end.  Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: can you attach a debugger and get a stack trace when the program is below `main()`?

Comment: What about removing all the static so that you will have a chance to see where error occurs?

Comment: Your program is working well on Boost trunk.

Comment: I have seen similar behavior on OS X only. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Not using namespaces instead of all static classes is sore to the eyes.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your compiler's optimization level the following code:

```
while ( curIndex_ < 0 )
            stateChange_.wait( lock );
```

could be interpreted as

```
while ( true )
            stateChange_.wait( lock );
```

because the variable curIndex_ does not change inside this while loop. This may lead to the deadlock you mentioned. You can declare curIndex_ as volatile in order to force the compiler not to optimize accesses to this variable.

Comment: No, `volatile` is not for multithreading, it should be an atomic variable. See http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484

Comment: yes if you are using a compiler that supports it, which I currently do not have :)

Comment: If you're using Boost and your compiler doesn't support atomics, look into Boost.Atomic (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/atomic.html)

Comment: You may not have `std::atomic` but most platforms support some form of platform-specific atomic operations on atomic variables. In any case, in this question the variable is protected by a mutex, so the answer is simply wrong.